# Google text to speech tts api doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, google-text-to-speech

Hello I tried using Google TTS api to convert text to speech.

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello
```

However this doesn't play in browser.What's the issue ? This used to work till last year.

Answer (score 1):

Google has deprecated free access to the API, you now need an API key. Please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The example noted [here](https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1728771#gistcomment-1723144) worked for me:

```
wget -q -U Mozilla -O output.mp3 \
"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=Test&tl=En-gb"
```